# When using 'android.intent.action.SEND' the receiving activity doesn't go back to the activity that initiated the share

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that has two activities.

- `ConfigActivity`
- `ShareActivity`

`ConfigActivity` is also the default activity for the app. The `ShareActivity` is only accessed when another application shares something i.e. the Gallery sharing a photo.

`ShareActivity` collects some information from the user and then finishes. The problem is when `ShareActivity` calls `finish()` `ConfigActivity` is shown. I want the Gallery or whichever app that initiated the share to come back.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="2.0beta" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application android:name=".TestApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.ConfigActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.ActivationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testapp.ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MemoryService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.testapp.action.send_to_media_gateway" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried a different scenario. I force stopped my app. I go into the devices Gallery and share an image. I select my app to share with which loads `ShareActivity`. I submit the information and it goes back to Gallery as I want. Then I ran my app which loads `ConfigActivity` since it's the main activity. If I then go to Gallery and attempt to share an image via `ShareActivity` when it's finished it goes to `ConfigActivity` and not the Gallery.

Comment: I dont understand, so when you are in your ConfigActivity you can, for example, go to your gallery, and click share, then after the ShareActivity you want to go back to the gallery rather than the configactivity?

Comment: @Clay - Say you're in Gallery and you share something. My app comes up as an option and you select it. A simple activity (ShareActivity) comes up and has a field for email. When you fill it out and hit the submit button it does it's thing and finishes "finish()" the activity. The activity always goes to the last active screen of my app (in most cases ConfigActivity). I want it to go back to the gallery.

Comment: @DavidWasser I've updated my question with the manifest and another scenario that I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

to the `<activity>` tag for `ShareActivity`

This should ensure that `ShareActivity` opens in the task that is doing the sharing and not in the task where your application is running.